# NGINX subdomain Redirect issue

Tags: nginx, redirect, url-rewriting, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to redirect my new site subdomin in nginx

```
www.test.com/video/ >>> www.test.com/v/
```

want to rewrite /video/ to /v/ though

**so i tried this in nginx conf.d**

```
server {
    server_name www.test.com/video/;
    return 301 http://www.test.com/v/$request_uri;
}
```

**and**

```
server {
  server_name  www.test.com/video/;
  rewrite ^(.*) http://www.test.com/v/ permanent;
}
```

even this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.test.com/video/;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://www.test.com/v/;
    }
}
```

but its always redirect to a fix url

```
curl -I http://www.test.com/v/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: awselb/2.0
Date: Mon, 10 Oct 2022 12:14:03 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 134
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://www.test.com:443/v/
```

Can anyone help me with this ? What is wrong here ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, `/v` is the real name and you want to tunnel `/video` calls to it.

Maybe a configuration like this could match :

```
server {
    listen 8022; # so 74014922;
    server_name www.test.com; # here your server name

    root D:/WEB; # and here the root path of your site (I'm under Windows, sorry ^^)

    location /video { # the path from root directive value
        proxy_pass http://www.test.com/v;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

**EDIT : alternative - `nginx` redirection**

Finally, I think there is no need to look further a native redirection, as follow :

```
    location /video {
        rewrite /video(.*)$ /v$1 redirect;
    }
```

As far as we can hope, it should do the job, please let me know.

Comment: I have tried it my default conf.d  , ssl.conf and redirect.conf but same output as earlier its always redirect to a fix URL. "Location: https://www.test.com:443/v/"

Comment: @SantoshBaruah, I propose an alternative. My internal tests seems ok. `localhost:8080/video/test/` redirects to `localhost:8080/v/test/`

Comment: I did test with  : server_name www.test.com/video/;
location /video {
        rewrite /video(.*)$ /v/$1 redirect;
    }
but same output as earlier, curl -I http://www.test.com/video/  Location: https://www.test.com:443/video/

Comment: @SantoshBaruah, `server_name www.test.com/video/` looks strange for me. Why not simply `server_name www.test.com` ?
May you try with `localhost` on a specific port ?

Comment: i did try with the said config (server_name www.test.com;) , the output is same , curl -I http://www.test.com/video/ output : Location: https://www.test.com:443/video/
and curl -I https://www.test.com/video/ and output https://review.test.com:443/video/ im not albe to rectify why im geeting the same fixed output same time ?